# int-ftp:outbound-gateway - handling exceptions (file already exists on GET)

Tags: spring-integration

I am using int-ftp:outbound-gateway sample given in GITHUB. 
Its working for me. The problem I am facing is : If the file already exists in my local its not overwriting with the file from FTP. Its throwing the following error and the execution stops : 
I want to overwrite the local copy... Any idea on how to handle this scenario ?

```
WARNING: failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
Throwable occurred: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Local file \TOPROCESS\UserLastLoginData2015-10-08.csv already exists
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.get(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:677)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway$2.doInSession(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:423)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway$2.doInSession(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:419)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:295)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doGet(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:419)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:381)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Starting with Spring Integration version 4.1.4](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3706), you can set `mode="REPLACE"` on the outbound gateway.